# Region plot of transformed region giving odd result

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions, geometric-transform

I tried applying a transformation to a rectangle:

```
RegionPlot[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {#1^(1/3) + #2, 1 + #2} &]]
```

giving

[image]

In reality, it ought to be giving a parallelogram-shaped region, based on simply transforming a bunch of points:

```
Table[{#1^(1/3) + #2, 1 + #2} &[k, j], {k, 0, 1, 0.02}, {j, 0, 1, 
   0.02}] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong here? Am I using `TransformedRegion` wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me to be a bug in `RegionPlot`. I say fhis beccause

```
DiscretizeRegion @ TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {#1^(1/3) + #2, 1 + #2} &]
```

gives

[image: region]

as expected.

Comment: I filed a bug report at tech support.